# Error when uploading images. botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am storing profile pictures for my app in AWS S3. I have it working on my localhost, but when I  do it in production, I get the error:

```
[Wed Nov 04 00:34:53.554807 2020] [:error] [pid 14967] [remote 172.31.2.3:112] botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Below is a portion of my bucket policy pertaining to PutObject:

```
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "*****",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:::******role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::******/resources/environments/logs/*"
        },
```

I'm not sure why this would work on my localhost but not when I deploy it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are running this from an EC2 instance? Are you sure you are not using any other AWS credentials, roles, except the one listed in the policy?

Comment: @Marcin I'm running this from an EC2 instance via Elastic Beanstalk. I'm pretty sure I'm not using any other AWS users or roles, but I'm fairly new to AWS. Looking at my IAM console, I've only got 1 user. As for the roles, I have 8 different roles listed on IAM for various AWS services, but I'm not sure how to check if I'm using a role improperly.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this to work. It required me to make a new role policy for the role used in my bucket policy. Here's my custom role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-*****/profile-pictures/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-*****"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure why I had to make this policy. In my bucket policy, I already had these actions allowed with this role. It could be that I had to explicitly specify the profile picture resource folder, but I'm not sure.